# Exact sequence $0\to A \to B \to C \to D \to 0$ and $0\to A[2]\to B[2] \to C[2] \to ?\to 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $A,B,C,D$ be abelian groups. Let $A$ be a finite group.
Let $0\to A \to B \to C \to D \to 0$ be exact sequence of abelian groups.

In this situation, I want to determine what is「$X$」in the exact sequence $$0\to A[2]\to B[2] \to C[2]\to X \to 0. $$ Here, morphism in this sequence is restriction of the first sequence.

Here, $A[2]=\{a\in A \mid 2a=0\}$.

How can I do that ?

I heard a hint that complexes $0\to A[2]\to B[2] \to C[2] \to D[2]\to 0$ and $0 \to A/2A \to B/2B \to C/2C \to 0$ have the same cohomology but shifted by $2$. But I'm sticking with understanding how to make the six term complex $0\to A[2]\to B[2] \to C[2] \to D[2]\to 0$ into exact sequence.

I also tried to calculate **Ext** functor, but in vain.
Related: [Suppose $0\to A\to B\to C\to D\to 0$ is exact. Let $0\to A[2]\to B[2]\to C[2]\to X\to 0$ be an exact sequence. Then, $X$ is finite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4816752/suppose-0-to-a-to-b-to-c-to-d-to-0-is-exact-let-0-to-a2-to-b2-to-c2-to)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried separating your exact sequence into two short exact sequences and applying the snake lemma to the $\cdot 2$ map?

Comment: @bsbb$4$ Yes, if we apply snake lemma to $0\to A\to B\to img\to 0$ and $0\to Kerh\to C\to D\to 0$, we gain $A[2]\to B[2]\to img[2]\to A/2A \to B/2B \to img/2img \to・・・$ and $0 \to (kerh)[2] \to C[2] \to D[2] \to kerh/2kerh \to C/2C \to D/2D\to・・・$, but we cannot gain anything from this.

Comment: @bsbb4  Is it possible to extract 6-term exact sequence of 2-part in this situation ?

Comment: Exactness of the original sequence means that $\mathrm{im}(g) = \mathrm{ker}(h)$, so that might help as well

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? You can fit this group into various exact sequences but there isn’t going to be a direct “formula” for it.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Original motivation is to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458533/global-duality-theorem-for-2-part

Comment: Write A[n] = Hom(Z/nZ,A) and use the Ext functor.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Which five term exact sequence do you apply Ext functor ?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey. I want to embed $X$ into the group whose order is as small as possible. What kind of 'fit' in your mind ?